# Rows number check in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to check if there were any records (more than 0) in my database table:

```
        $ifExists = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `characters` WHERE userid = ?', array(Auth::id()));
```

Now I am checking if there are more than 0:

```
   if($ifExists > 0){
                return Redirect('/board');
            }
            else{
                return view('intro');
            }
```

It always takes me to the `/board`. But there are many rows in this database table.

The `echo $ifExists;` shows me `[{"COUNT(*)":0}]`

How do I check this number?

Comment: You need more details on this question. Try verbose mode to check what the query is. Other than, I think we cannot help you that much

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM characters`. I think, it's returning object, so your check must be: `$ifExists->counter > 0` after you add `AS counter` inside your query

Comment: @jaro1989 It was actually `$ifExists[0]->counter` but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yeah. It's an array of objects. So, echoing of such variables will tell you almost nothing. `var_dump` is better, xDebug - is the best approach.

Comment: What is your `DB` class?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It is something built in laravel5. Since I am beginner, not sure what it is exactly :D

Comment: You should add the [laravel] tag to your question

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

```
$ifExists = DB::table('characters')->where('userid', Auth::id())->count();
```

If you do it like in your question, you will receive an array of objects.

If you only want to check for existens of entries and do not need the count, you can just use the `exists()` function whitch will return you a boolean:

```
$ifExists = DB::table('characters')->where('userid', Auth::id())->exists();

if($ifExists){
    return Redirect('/board');
}else{
    return view('intro');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I've done PHP, but from the looks of it you get a result object from the database. That object is 1 object.
I think that's why it's always redirecting to /board.

Not sure how to do this in PHP, but you want to get the value of "COUNT(*)" from the object for your if statement. Hope that helps :)